# Modifying an object directly vs modifying it indirectly through a copied instance (and then making the original equal to it)

Tags: java, performance, object, copy

How much is the overhead for the copy->modify->copy back method? Let's say I have an object that have a couple of methods and 5 pieces of 2 dimensional 1000*1000 arrays. Is it a good practice to copy an object like this to compute on every 10-100ms or not? I guess not, but my code would look 10 times neater.

Is there some secret technique to achieve this by no actual copying, just using some "different -short- name" for the object (instead of the original very long path)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java works by references, you will never obtain a copy of a non primitive type with the assignment operator, unless you are explicitly requesting a copy (by an instance method for example). Actually it works by value, on references: what is effectively assigned (and copied) is the reference on the heap to the object.

What I mean is that if you have

```
YourObject o = otherComplex.path.to.a.different.variable;
```

What's happening is that `o` is an alias to the other variable, they both refer to the same object on the heap so they both have same performance implications.

You don't neither need to assign it back, eg

```
YourObject o = otherComplex.path.to.a.different.variable;
o.method();
o.field = ...;
otherComplex.path.to.a.different.variable = o;
```

This is unnecessary as you are just reassigning values which are already equivalent.

Comment: Thank you, there was serious misunderstanding on my side.